# How to run an Angular app on a Node server?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I would like to run my app with `express` on a Node server.

My `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/my-app/index.html'))
});

app.listen(80, () => {
  console.log('Server started!')
})
```

But when I'm trying to view my website on `localhost` nothing appears. Can you help me?

Comment: (1) you get any error at `res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/my-app/index.html'))`... (2) also when you do `localhost:[80]/` in your browser, what do you see? (3) try changing the port of your app.listen to 8080 instead of 80

Answer (score 18):

Hope this would help you.

1) Run:

```
ng build --prod
```

This will create a *dist* folder. Used for production.

2) Run:

```
npm install --save express
```

To install express and save it as dependency in the project.

3) Create a file in root: *./server.js*

4) Copy this code. Don't forget to modify with your name project

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/my-app-name'));

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`App running on: http://localhost:${port}`));
```

5) To run the *server.js* file

```
node server.js
```

Comment: Hello I have similar setup. When I hit `http://localhost:3000` page loads correctly. But when I try `http://localhost:3000/login` page loads without CSS. Browser console shows below error - `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).`

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution !

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 3000;

const root = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'my-app');


app.get('*' ,function(req, res) {
  fs.stat(root + req.path, function(err){
    if(err){
        res.sendFile("index.html", { root });
    }else{
        res.sendFile(req.path, { root });
    }
  })
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port '+ port);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in just very few steps...

**1). Run ng build --prod** (If you get budgets error than increase the budget in angular.json file according to the error)

2). After above command, a dist folder will be generated containing your project folder, move this project folder which is present inside dist folder from angular project in to your node project say inside public folder (public/your_build_angular_project).

3). Now in your node main file say index.js or app.js, include these lines

```
const path = require('path');
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/your_build_angular_project')));
```

4). Now serve your node server then when you hit it, you will get your angular project running

Hope this will help you or somebody else! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sample angularjs app directory is here :

```
AngularApp->myApp->
AngularApp->myApp->controllers
AngularApp->myApp->views
AngularApp->myApp->services
AngularApp->myApp->app.js
AngularApp->myApp->index.html
```

Create a package.json file and insert below code in it:

(Location : AngularApp->package.json)

```
    {
   "name": "myApp",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "description": "My Project",
   "dependencies": {
        "express": "*"
    },
   "engine": "node >=0.6.x",
   "scripts": {
         "start": "node server.js"
    },
   "main": "server.js",
   "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": ""
    },
   "author": "myApp",
   "license": "myApp",
   "bugs": {
        "url": ""
    },
   "homepage": "/"
}
```

Create server.js:
(Location: AngularApp->server.js )

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static("myApp")); // myApp will be the same folder name.
app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
 res.redirect('/'); 
});
app.listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log("MyProject Server is Listening on port 8080");
```

Run commnad 'npm install' after navigating to package.json file.

Run command 'npm start'. Open a browser and hit localhost:8080/